# Java Split RegEx not working

Tags: java, regex, split

I have been experiencing a lot of difficulties with a very simple task in java. Firstly I would like to split a String to array, every letter alone and use a **regex** (this is important because i will upgrade it for more complex regex after this but I firstly need this simple one to run)

```
    Stringbase = "artetbewrewcwewfd";       
    String arr2[] = base.split("\\.");
```

Why can't I do it like this?

```
    String base = "artetbewrewcwewfd";       
    String arr2[] = base.split("\\[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]");
```

nor even like this.

https://ideone.com/cCYVSc

https://ideone.com/DYnh3m

thank you for your time

Comment: So you try to split a String without any dot on a dot ... and what do you expext there? I mean you explicitly escaped your regex, so I guess you know what you're doing?

Comment: Try [`String arr2[] = "artetbew42rewcwewfd".split("(?!^)(?=.)");`](https://ideone.com/Yv87rF)

Comment: dot is a symbol for any character in regex as far as I know?

Comment: An *unescaped* dot (or not inside a character class) *with `DOTALL` mode* matches any character.

Comment: Yes, dot `.`, you're looking for the character dot, which is `\\.` and something different.

Comment: Let's put it clear: what do you need to get in the end? What is expected output for a given input?

Comment: You have already wrote what i needed Wiktor, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help then, I posted as an answer.

Comment: I say, it's so unfair to downvote this question. OP asked a question with which he is having trouble and he posted his effort as well. Why should he receive any downvote is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\\.` (an escaped dot) in your first regex matches a literal dot character (and your string has no dots, thus, the `split` returns the whole string).

The second `"\\[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]"` pattern matches a *sequence* of `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`, because you ruined the *character class* construct by escaping the first `[` (and an escaped `[` matches a literal `[`, thus, the closing `]` also is treated as a literal symbol, not a special construct character).

To just split before *each character* in a string, you can use

```
String arr2[] = "artetbew42rewcwewfd".split("(?!^)(?=.)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
// => [a, r, t, e, t, b, e, w, 4, 2, r, e, w, c, w, e, w, f, d]
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Yv87rF)

Here, `(?!^)` fails the match at the very start of the string (so as not to return an empty space as first element) and `(?=.)` is a positive lookahead to match before any character but a newline.

If you want to match before a newline, too, use `Pattern.DOTALL` flag, or add `(?s)` before the pattern.